# Could not inherit file classes/pypi.bbclass with meta-raspberrypi Yocto Bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have cloned **Poky** in a folder as follows:

```
~/Yocto/poky/
```

I checked out a branch for **Rocko** as mentioned in the [Quick Start Guide](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.2/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html)

I was successful in creating a `qemu` according to the Guide. I wish to create Raspberry Pi Image and hence I cloned the **meta-raspberrypi** in the `~/Yocto/poky/` directory as well as **openembedded** in the same directory. Hence the current directory structure is as follows:

```
 ~/Yocto/poky/
          -- meta-raspberrypi/
          -- meta-openembedded/
```

I execute the `source oe-init-build-env` and change the content of the `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf` as follows

#### local.conf

```
MACHINE = "raspberrypi2"
```

#### bblayers.conf

```
  BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
  "
```

### ERROR

upon `bitbake rpi-basic-image`

```
ERROR: ParseError at /home/<user>/Yocto/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-devtools/python/rpio_0.10.0.bb:9: Could not inherit file classes/pypi.bbclass
```

On the [Yocto Mailing List](https://www.mail-archive.com/yocto@yoctoproject.org/msg36987.html) a similar query was resolved by adding `openembedded/meta-python` which already exists in my `bblayers` file.

I also tried changing the `meta-raspberrypi` branch to the **Rocko** by doing the following

```
 git checkout origin/rocko -b rocko
```

in order to be with the same **Poky** version of 2.4.2

but I still get the same error.

How should I go about this error in order to create a Rpi Image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your layers need to use matching branches. In this case your meta-python is probably too new (it no longer has the pypi class because it was moved to oe-core). Checkout the rocko branch of meta-openembedded repo and things should start working.

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question! you went and answered it for me! :)

Comment: I followed these steps but now get: "Unable to connect to bitbake server, or start one"

Comment: @CodeJunkie are you using Linux Machine or Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows?

Comment: i have tried it on docker with ubuntu and on a ubuntu vm directly.

Comment: i have the same problem and i dont want to to use the rocko branch because packages are old i this branch. How can i use the master branch and resolve this problem? desperately need help!